# Animate ImageView drawable colorchange

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview

I'm trying to change the color of a drawable shape with an animation. The drawable is shown in an ImageView and color is normally set using setColorFilter().

I've tried using TransitionDrawable and ObjectAnimator but no matter what i tried nothing happened.

Does anyone know how to do this or perhaps if i'm doing something wrong?

This is the shape that I'm trying to change the color off:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid
        android:color="@color/circle"/>

    <size
        android:width="70dp"
        android:height="70dp"/>
</shape>
```

And the code off my last attempt using a TransistionDrawable:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    out = new TransitionDrawable(new Drawable[]{getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.white_circle, getTheme()), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.circle, getTheme())});
} else {
    out = new TransitionDrawable(new Drawable[]{getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.white_circle), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.circle)});
}
out.setCrossFadeEnabled(true);
out.startTransition(1000);
```

where white_circle is exactly the same as circle but colored white

Comment: Please show us your code and we might be able to help out!

Comment: @JasonWyatt sorry, I had to leave earlier but wanted to post the question already in case someone had an easy solution, I added the code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I didn't find a way to change the color of a shape in Android with an animation, I used another solution.

I created the object twice, displayed on the exact same place, one with the startcolor, one with the endcolor. When a transition is needed I simply fade out the old image and fade in the new one.

Should anyone still find a way to animate this without using a second object feel free to answer this question.